# Estimate the Expected Run Time of a loop or nested loops

Tags: r, loops, time, runtime, systemtime

I am using the R programming language. I am interested in knowing if there is a way to estimate the actual run time of a procedure (relative to the "strength" of your computer) without actually running that procedure.

For example, suppose I want to determine how long the below procedure takes to run on my computer :

```
 library(caret)
    library(rpart)

#generate data

a = rnorm(80000, 10, 10)
b = rnorm(80000, 10, 5)
c = rnorm(80000, 5, 10)
group <- sample( LETTERS[1:2], 80000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5,0.5))
group_1 <- 1:80000

#put data into a frame
d = data.frame(a,b,c, group, group_1)
d$group = as.factor(d$group)

e <- d
vec1 <- sample(200:300, 5)
vec2 <- sample(400:500,5)
vec3 <- sample(700:800,5)
z <- 0
df <- expand.grid(vec1, vec2, vec3)
df$Accuracy <- NA

for (i in seq_along(vec1)) { 
    for (j in seq_along(vec2)) {
        for (k in seq_along(vec3)) {
            # d <- e
            d$group_2 = as.integer(ifelse(d$group_1 < vec1[i] , 0, ifelse(d$group_1 >vec1[i]  & d$group_1 < vec2[j] , 1, ifelse(d$group_1 >vec2[j]  & d$group_1 < vec3[k] , 2,3))))
            
            d$group_2 = as.factor(d$group_2)
            
            
            
            TreeFit <- rpart(group_2 ~ ., data = d[,-5])
            
            pred <- predict(
                TreeFit,
                d[,-5], type = "class")
            
            con <- confusionMatrix(
                d$group_2,
                pred) 
            
            #update results into table
            #final_table[i,j] = con$overall[1]
            z <- z + 1
            df$Accuracy[z] <- con$overall[1]
        }
    }
}

head(df)
```

I could just "sandwich" that procedure between the following lines of code and determine how long it took

```
start_time <- proc.time()

#copy and paste the entire block of code here

 proc.time() - start_time

#results

 user  system elapsed 
  51.86    0.36   52.22
```

But suppose it is a really lengthy procedure and I want to roughly estimate how long it will take for my computer to run before actually running it - is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using nested loops, instead of timing the whole thing, try timing the first of, or small number of, iterations of the loop..

E.g. instead of

```
for (i in seq_along(vec1)) { 
    for (j in seq_along(vec2)) {
        for (k in seq_along(vec3)) {
```

try iterating along only the first few elements of each

```
for (i in seq_along(vec1[1:3])) { 
    for (j in seq_along(vec2[1:3])) {
        for (k in seq_along(vec3[1:3])) {
```

or whatever makes sense for your use case.

Once you know the timing for a small subset of the data, you could make an educated guess as to how long it may take for larger datasets.

Comment: Thank you! This is what i was thinking of... i wasn't sure if i could approach the problem this way. Thank you!